# Counting triangles in a graph by iteratively removing high-degree nodes

Tags: python, performance, networkx, graph-theory

Computing `nx.triangles(G)` on an undirected graph with about 150 thousand nodes and 2 million edges, is currently very slow (on the scale of 80 hours). If the node degree distribution is highly skewed, is there any problem with counting triangles using the following procedure?

```py
import networkx as nx

def largest_degree_node(G):
    # this was improved using suggestion by Stef in the comments
    return max(G.degree(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

def count_triangles(G):
    G=G.copy()
    triangle_counts = 0
    while len(G.nodes()):
        focal_node = largest_degree_node(G)
        triangle_counts += nx.triangles(G, nodes=[focal_node])[focal_node]
        G.remove_node(focal_node)
    return triangle_counts

G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(1000, 0.1)

# compute triangles with nx
triangles_nx = int(sum(v for k, v in nx.triangles(G).items()) / 3)

# compute triangles iteratively
triangles_iterative = count_triangles(G)

# assertion passes
assert int(triangles_nx) == int(triangles_iterative)
```

The assertion passes, but I am wary that there are some edge cases where this iterative approach will not work.

Comment: I assume this is faster because each triangle is only counted once?  But there's a lot of effort that goes into sorting the nodes.  Does this sorting really give you any advantage?  And is it such an advantage that it's worth resorting them each time?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. In practice I see a substantial improvement in calculation time (for my graph, the difference is about 8 minutes vs 80 hours)... just worried that I am missing something.

Comment: Have you considered replacing `return sorted(G.degree(), key=lambda x: x[1])[-1][0]` with `return max(G.degree(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]` for `largest_degree_node`?

Comment: Thank you, that will improve the efficiency a bit!

Comment: Alternatively, since you're repeatedly looking for a maximum element, you could use a maxheap. But you'd need to reheapify it when the degrees change because of `G.remove_node(focal_node)`. So I'm not sure if it's really worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the graph is **not directed** (ie. `G.is_directed() == False`), the number of triangles can be efficiently found by finding **nodes that are both neighbors of neighbors and direct neighbors of a same node**. Pre-computing and pre-filtering the neighbors of nodes so that each triangle is counted only once helps to improve a lot the execution time. Here is the code:

```py
nodeNeighbours = {
    # The filtering of the set ensure each triangle is only computed once
    node: set(n for n in edgeInfos.keys() if n > node)
    for node, edgeInfos in G.adjacency()
}

triangleCount = sum(
    len(neighbours & nodeNeighbours[node2])
    for node1, neighbours in nodeNeighbours.items()
    for node2 in neighbours
)
```

The above code is about **12 times faster** than the original iterative solution on the example graph. And up to **72 times faster** on `nx.erdos_renyi_graph(15000, 0.005)`.

Comment: Can you turn this into an improved version of `nx.triangles(G)`?  If so, can you suggest the change at https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues?

Comment: @Joel Good idea. Thank you. I am not sure this fit their need, but I submitted an issue for this [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/5246). The generalized code for bi-graphs producing the same results than NetworkX is still much faster. The proposed function only work on the full graph but I guess this is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

A *faster solution* consist in using [**Numba**](https://numba.pydata.org/) and perform the computation with **multiple threads**. Unfortunately, this method is *much more complex* (hence this separate answer).

The idea is to first convert the graph into Numpy arrays, then balance the work between the thread, and finally apply the algorithm provided in the alternative answer (using multiple thread and Numpy arrays). The graphs is encoded using four Numpy arrays:

- `nodes`: contains all the nodes IDs;
- `allNeighbours`: contains all the neighbours of all nodes;
- `neighbourSlices`: contains for each node, the slice (start+end index) of the array `allNeighbours` (so to be able to fetch the neighbours of a node);
- `nodeIdToPos`: contains the index of the node in `nodes` based on its ID.

Here is the code:

```py
# Split the nodes so the work (based on the slices) is balanced.
# Returns the (start,stop) slices of the nodes
@nb.njit('(int_[:,::1], int_)')
def splitSlices(neighbourSlices, count):
    n = np.int64(neighbourSlices.shape[0])
    m = neighbourSlices[-1, 1] if neighbourSlices.size > 0 else 0
    workSize = np.empty((count, 2), dtype=np.int_)
    curPos = 0
    for i in range(count):
        for j in range(curPos, n):
            stop = neighbourSlices[j, 1]
            if stop >= m * (i + 1) // count:
                workSize[i, 0] = curPos
                curPos = j + 1
                workSize[i, 1] = curPos
                break
    if count > 0:
        workSize[0, 0] = 0
        workSize[-1, 1] = n
    return workSize


@nb.njit('(int_[::1], int_[:,::1], int_[::1])', parallel=True)
def filterNeighbours(nodes, neighbourSlices, allNeighbours):
    outNeighbourSlices = np.empty(neighbourSlices.shape, dtype=np.int_)
    outAllNeighbours = np.empty(allNeighbours.size//2, dtype=np.int_)

    curPos = 0
    for i in range(nodes.size):
        curNode = nodes[i]
        start, stop = neighbourSlices[i]
        outNeighbourSlices[i, 0] = curPos
        for neighbour in allNeighbours[start:stop]:
            if neighbour > curNode:
                outAllNeighbours[curPos] = neighbour
                curPos += 1
        outNeighbourSlices[i, 1] = curPos

    threadCount = nb.np.ufunc.parallel.get_num_threads()
    nodeSlides = splitSlices(outNeighbourSlices, threadCount)

    for threadId in nb.prange(threadCount):
        start, stop = nodeSlides[threadId]
        for i in range(start, stop):
            start, stop = outNeighbourSlices[i]
            outAllNeighbours[start:stop].sort()

    return (outNeighbourSlices, outAllNeighbours)


@nb.njit('int_(int_[::1], int_[:,::1], int_[::1])', parallel=True)
def computeTriangle(nodes, neighbourSlices, allNeighbours):
    nodeIdToPos = np.empty(np.max(nodes)+1, dtype=np.int_)
    for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
        nodeIdToPos[node] = i

    neighbourSlices, allNeighbours = filterNeighbours(nodes, neighbourSlices, allNeighbours)

    threadCount = nb.np.ufunc.parallel.get_num_threads()
    nodeSlides = splitSlices(neighbourSlices, threadCount)

    s = 0
    for threadId in nb.prange(threadCount):
        start, stop = nodeSlides[threadId]
        for i in range(start, stop):
            node1 = nodes[i]
            start1, stop2 = neighbourSlices[i]
            neighbours1 = allNeighbours[start1:stop2]
            for node2 in neighbours1:
                start2, stop2 = neighbourSlices[nodeIdToPos[node2]]
                neighbours2 = allNeighbours[start2:stop2]
                for node3 in neighbours2:
                    if node3 > node2:
                        foundId = np.searchsorted(neighbours1, node3)
                        s += foundId < neighbours1.size and neighbours1[foundId] == node3
    return s

# Conversion to Numpy arrays

edgeCount = sum(len(neighbours) for _, neighbours in G.adjacency())
nodes = np.fromiter(G.nodes(), dtype=np.int_)
neighbourSlices = np.empty((len(G), 2), dtype=np.int_)
allNeighbours = np.empty(edgeCount, dtype=np.int_)

curPos = 0
for i, nodeInfos in enumerate(G.adjacency()):
    node, edgeInfos = nodeInfos
    neighbours = np.fromiter(edgeInfos.keys(), dtype=np.int_)
    neighbourSlices[i, 0] = curPos
    neighbourSlices[i, 1] = curPos + neighbours.size
    allNeighbours[curPos:curPos+neighbours.size] = neighbours
    curPos += neighbours.size

# Actual computation (very fast)

triangleCount = computeTriangle(nodes, neighbourSlices, allNeighbours)
```

On my 6-core machine, this solution **45 times faster** than the original iterative solution on the example graph and **up to 290 times faster** on `nx.erdos_renyi_graph(15000, 0.005)`. It is much much faster than other methods when the average degree (`N_edges/N_nodes`) is big.

Unfortunately, most of the time is spent in the (sequential) conversion of the graph into Numpy arrays. Thus, if you want a faster method (eg. 2~3 times faster), then you certainly need to use a native language implementation (like C or C++). Or to work mainly with Numpy array instead of NetworkX graphs, but this approach is clearly less flexible and complex to archive.

Comment: This is very interesting, thanks! I am interested in using numba and some other parallel computing features (e.g. dask, ray, cupy/cu*) within the graph context, so will study your solution with interest. :)

Comment: Interesting, but on some of the real-world graphs I am finding that the numba-based solution seems to be about 3 times slower relative to the [other solution you proposed on GitHub](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/5246)...

Comment: And it seems that bulk of the time is taken by graph reshape, so I understand your comment at the end better. Thanks!